# How to precisely select a very wide mesh?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I have this very wide but thin tubular mesh (150 cm wide x 150 cm deep x 0.5 mm high), that I want to convert into an outline. It looks kind of like a fishnet thrown on the ground. I want to take just the outline of it, which is all the vertices that are on a given Z coordinate. When I zoom close enough to be able to select the vertices by Z coordinate, I am too close to be able to select a meaningful amount of the mesh (regardless of if I'm using X-ray or not).

Imagine the sample below but repeated 8 times in Y and 15 times in X
[image: sample image]

Is there a way to select very precisely over multiple screen widths? I've tried using a rectangle mesh (that I can position very precisely) but I'd need to be able to use it to do a sort of "selection knife project" on the "fishnet" mesh which I don't know how to do.

### Context

I have this very large 3D mesh that I want to knife project on in a complicated way. In order to do that I have a complicated Nurbs curve that I thickened (I need this precise spacing between each side) and converted to a mesh so that I can transform it to an outline as that makes it possible to knife project with.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an adjustable selection operator for this, so it's:

- Select a vertex on your net's mid-Z, (active) .
- **Header > Select > Side of Active**  set to 'Aligned Axis' and Z

[image]

The threshold may need adjustment to capture all edges of interest, and exclude others. (Progressive selections can be made by tactical <kbd>H</kbd> hiding.)

Comment: Do you know if there is something about a minimum distance between the vertices? It seems to work but have too large of a step (so it selects everything)

Comment: Found it, the threshold is not actually 0, you can reduce it clicking into it. You solved it, thanks a lot for the pointer!

Comment: @OlivierDiotte Sorry... I should have illustrated better. Glad it worked for you :) Edited.

Comment: @RobinBetts (I cannot comment under deleted answers): No, sorry, I'm just tired and didn't realize while reading the question that the object has much different dimensions than shown in the example.. I wish I knew a way because sometimes it is the only possible way to do it. I just discovered recently that when you drag a selection box and hold space, you can move it (if you accidentally started in the wrong position for example), but you cannot move the view with this.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  Ahh, thanks! the space-trick I didn't know :) .. I thought I read/heard somewhere this was being dealt with by the devs.. but tricky, for a view-space selection.. you'd have to prevent rotation of the view, I suppose, and that opens a whole can of inconsistency-worms.